# Properly pronounce "cabellos" in Argentinian dialect of Spanish

Tags: pronunciación, argentina

Modern day sources [suggest](https://youtu.be/c5U70surkQo) [dʒ] for 'll' in *cabello/cabellos* in Argentinian Spanish.

However, this not-so-old [recording](https://youtu.be/GXeoHjFwLHU) clearly has [s] (not [dʒ]) for 'll' in *cabellos*.

Does this mean that Argentinian Spanish evolved since 1977 (in this regard at least)? Or do these two examples actually represent different dialects?

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: Bien ahí, locooo! Al fin una pregunta sobre la Argentina, y qué temaikén que eleigiste para preguntar! Ahora te respondo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no hubo ninguna evolución repentina en el castellano ríoplatense en torno a lo que es la pronunciación. Hay al menos tres fonemas que se usan para ‘ll’ y ‘y’, que dependen fundamentalmente de la zona:

- **[La ‘ll’ fuerte (o la ‘sh’) /ʃ/ /ʒ/](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fricativa_postalveolar_sorda)**: Es la forma más común de pronunciar ambas letras.
- **[La ‘ll’ media (o la ‘i’ fuerte) /ʝ/](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fricativa_palatal_sonora)**: La usan los mendocinos y algunas personas del Norte para la ‘ll’ y la ‘y’. Si mal no recuerdo, también la usan los misioneros (los que son de Misiones) para la ‘y’.
- **[La ‘ll’ suave (o ‘li’) /ʎ/](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aproximante_lateral_palatal)**: La usan los misioneros para la ‘ll’. Es el mismo sonido que se escucha en ‘gli’ en el italiano.

Hasta donde sé, [el fonema /d͡ʒ/](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africada_postalveolar_sonora) (la ‘g’ italiana) no es en sí mismo propio de la Argentina ni de ninguna variante del castellano. Pero, debido a que nuestra pronunciación es de las más fáciles que puedan haber, hay muchos alófonos. Entre ellos, están /ʃ/ y /d͡ʒ/. Así que, si en algún sitio ves que aparece /d͡ʒ/, en realidad sería /ʃ/; pero éstos se toman como equivalentes así que no hay problema de intercambiarlos.

La primera pronunciación que escuchaste fue /kaβeʃo/. Si mal no escuché, la segunda (la del cantante) sería  /kaβeʒo/, parece una ‘sh’ un poco más suavizada pero que sigue considerándose fuerte. Pero en ningún momento el cantante dice ‘cabeso’ con /s/.

Comment: En la canción No llores por mí, Argentina, interpretada por Nacha Guevara, la ll me suena un poco raro.  Casi parece como si se intentara otra manera de pronunciarlo.

Comment: @WalterMitty Yo escucho /ʒ/ en la ll, similar a la canción del OP

Comment: I used to watch *Futbol para todos* when it was on air, and all commentators (usually as many as four assigned for a single game) would pronounce distinct  /ʃ/  in *tarjeta amarilla* or family names like *Asprilla*.

This is why I am a bit surprised to hear /ʒ/ for the same or similar words

Comment: @vtm11 Pasa pasa. En inglés hay algunos alófonos también, aunque no tantos como en el español. Si querés reconocer más, podés mirar el debate presidencial que se hizo hoy. Vas a ver como contrasta la pronunciación de Schiaretti (que es cordobés) con el resto de los debatientes (que son de Buenos Aires)